# What is the opposite of a retronym?

Tags: nouns, terminology, antonyms

A retronym is the name given to an obsolete or older object to differentiate it from its newer replacement. Examples include "straight razor" (once just called "razor" until the modern razor), "analog clock," "manual transmission," etc.

What is the term for the corresponding word that shifts meaning from the retronym? (In these examples, how do "razor," "clock," and "transmission" function?)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Please can you spell out what you mean by '*...shifts meaning from the retronym?*'

Comment: It means is there a term for words such as "razor" that have changed meaning after a "retronym" was created from them. However I would argue that this isn't really what happened with any of the examples given. "Razor" doesn't mean "safety razor", "clock" doesn't mean "digital clock", and "transmission" doesn't mean "automatic transmission".

Comment: Maybe "watch" is a better example, versus the retronym "pocket watch?" Now, "watch" almost exclusively refers to wristwatches.

Comment: I could be wrong but didn't watch start out as watch with "pocket" added to specify a certain kind?

Comment: Also, manual transmission is still used to differentiate it from an automatic transmission.

Comment: What @MετάEd said. In practice, *razor, clock,* *transmission* still mean the same as before (they just identify whatever *current* physical implementation embodies the essential qualities of the original referent).

Comment: To steal a phrase from a domain based on taxonomy, how about "type specimen", the instance that defines the meaning of the word?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_(biology)

Comment: 'anteronym' would be the opposite by mindlessly adjoining the appropriate prefix. But that means nothing here. What you're looking for is 'word'. For example you have a synonym, what is the name of the thing that it is a synony of? It is 'word'.

Comment: Well, technically, the thing a synonym is a synonym of is also a synonym (it's normally a two-way relationship), but "word" would certainly do.

Comment: It's a type of [hypernym](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypernym): "razor" is a **hypernym** of "straight razor" and "safety razor". The meaning of hypernym is more general and doesn't necessarily involve a change of meaning (pet is a hypernym of cat and dog), so it's probably not what you want. But you're not getting anything else.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with MetaEd, FumbleFingers and Mitch. You can also think of it this way: 50 years from now, we may end up using the word **car** in reference _only_ to electric cars. **Fossil fuel cars** may then be a retronym for what most of the planet is driving around in today. Will that have any effect on what kind of word _car_ is?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the term for the corresponding word that shifts meaning from the retronym?

There isn't one.

There is a feeling that English should have a word for every conceivable concept - it doesn't. And making one up isn't going to cut it.

Comment: In September Oxford added fourteen words that begin with the letter alone. Someone had to come up with them. Did we really need a single word for the concept "[a] style of play in which a team upon losing possession puts immediate and intensive pressure on the opposition, even deep in the opposition's half, in an attempt to regain the ball at the earliest opportunity, prevent the opposing team from capitalizing on possession, and force mistakes in dangerous positions"?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Of course we can make up words, and people often do, but this is not the place for making up words.

Answer (score -1):

Oxford Dictionaries lists *[retronym](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/retronym)* as being a compound of *[retro-](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/retro-)* and *[-onym](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-onym)*, with *retro-* denoting something back in time.

By analogy, one can substitute *[ante-](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ante-)* to denote something earlier in time to yield: ***antenym***. (Not to be confused with *antonym*.)

As to what an *antenym* is, let's use the example from Oxford's definition of *retronym*:

> A new term created from an existing word in order to distinguish the
>   original referent of the existing word from a later one that is the
>   product of progress or technological development (e.g. *acoustic
>   guitar* for *guitar*).

So you can say that *guitar* is the *antenym* of the retronym *acoustic guitar.*

Comment: Now this is creating more confusion than expected, if you see this wikipedia post - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ante it says Latin meaning of Ante is before, so if we think only about the analogy, both **ante** and **retro** means older, before or back in time,isn't it ? Or can you please clarify with clear-cut  distinction between them ?

Comment: *pro-* is the usual Latin prefix for forward (*procedere* =go forwards vs *retrocedere* =go back), so *pronym* would be the logical term. By some strange definition of "logical".

Comment: The root word is not the opposite of the retronym, the opposite is the term which initially described the new thing when it first appeared. EG telephones were initially connected by wires and were just called telephones. When mobile phones appeared they were called mobile phones until they became more common than traditional phones. At that point people just called them phones and had to invent 'landline phone' as a retronym. The opposite of 'landline phone' is not 'phone' it's 'mobile phone' which was originally a _new coinage_ (which is probably the term required)

Answer (score -2):

Would "**protonym**" work for you? If I understand right, it's used for a similar purpose to what you are looking for in botany. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basionym

Comment: This is positively misleading: OED: **protonym**, n. *Now rare.* **The first person or thing of a certain name; something from which another person or thing takes its name.** -- 1880  The wrecked canal-boat, the Evening Star,..quenched in the twilight, with its heavenly protonym palpitating in the vapor above it.

Comment: @Greybeard I thought it could be borrowed from biology and used in that sense. Wiktionary says: "The first legitimate name of a taxon on which the current accepted name is based." If you generalize it, so that it doesn't have to apply to a taxon but to anything, then I think it matches the original request. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protonym

Comment: Also, "proto- [is a] word-forming element in compounds of Greek origin meaning "first, source, parent, preceding, earliest form, original, basic[...]"" in the words of etymonline.com https://www.etymonline.com/word/proto-

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for your questions,

I believe both **synonym and antonym** are opposites of retronym.

Comment: You should include an explanation of how synonym and antonym are opposites of retronym.